# How would I go about creating a react component library that imports CSS files

Tags: javascript, typescript, components

I wanted to create a React component library that didn't handle too much of the compilation load that other libraries like MUI handle. My thought was that I would use typescript to compile my code down to esm and cjs. I want to know how this would work with CSS files being imported into my React component files. Is there a way for me to keep this minimal setup while also including the CSS?